# Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

I have faced this problem on vs code after upgrading flutter to 3.10.1

Comment: Yes.  Flutter 3.10 has dart 3.0, and that switch went away.  Hopefully, you haven't needed it for a while.  Stop using it.

Comment: Thanks,It work for me. I remove "--no-sound-null-safety" argument from the "dart.flutterAdditionalArgs" setting.